# Spyder history pane issues

Tags: spyder

I use the spyder history pane to see what commands i have tried in the past, but recently i have noticed that it does not update as i type commands.
screenshot 1 shows the console and history pane, as you can see none of the console entries show in the history.
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMkQ.jpg)

screenshot 2 shows the console and history pane after re-starting spyder. You can see that the last three console entries from before restart are shown in the history pane.
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bIln.jpg)

I'm sure this isn't normal behaviour, but have failed to find any reference to it.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is very odd indeed. What's your Spyder version?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba spyder 5.2.1 Python 3.8.8 64-bit | Qt 5.12.9 | PyQt5 5.12.3 | Windows 10 
but i still have that issue with missing rtree >=0.9.7, i don't know if that has any bearing on this issue?

Comment: I tested this and (unfortunately) it appears to be broken (I don't know when that happened). I'll try to fix it for our next version (5.2.2), to be released next week.

Comment: Thanks for reporting it, by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a [bug](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17184) in Spyder, which will be fixed in version **5.2.2**, to be released in January 2022.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me discover that I was using an out-of-date version of spyder and python!